# Which language for client side" FaceBook apps?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to use the FaceBook Graph API to develop some apps (I won't go into details, I don't think it's relevant; let's just assume that I will use pretty much the entire entire API).

These are for personal use only and I would them to be client side/(Windows) desktop apps.

My specific question is which programming language I should use, given the following:
 - highest priority goes to using the language where I will find most examples and support and which is easiest to debug during development
 - I would have preferred Delphi, but it seems there there is no real support of examples
 - My PHP is very good and I run an Apache server on my PC
 - I have little experience of JavaScript, but it seemed easy enough to pick up
 - ditto for Java, although my C++ is strong

Please understand, this is not a "which is best?" flamewar question to be voted down; rather, it is a specific "which is best ***FOR ME***?" question which I hope that soemone can answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is very good for you, as you mentioned your php skills is very good, so just go with php, because you can easily debug php and figure our problems and there are allots of helps of php fb api's.... :)